# StringFormat in GroupBox header binding doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, xaml, bind, string-formatting, ivalueconverter

I'm trying to bind the header text of a`GroupBox` to a property and display it using `StringFormat`.

The first part works and it returns the text as expected. But I want the final text to be formatted. For example when I return `cm` I want it to be displayed as `Foundation Height (cm)`, but the code below only shows `cm`.

```
<GroupBox Header="{Binding CurrentTargetUnit, 
    Converter={StaticResource QuantityToTextConverter},
    ConverterParameter={x:Static enumerations:Quantity.Length},
    StringFormat='Foundation Height ({0})'}">
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: @FirstStep Still the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try without quotes

```
....
StringFormat=Foundation Height ({0})}">
```

**UPDATE**

As you have used  binding for header you should use `HeaderStringFormat`instead.

```
....
HeaderStringFormat=Foundation Height ({0})}">
```

Read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx) for more

Comment: It is odd! It seems that for `GroupBox`, `StringFormat` does not work. I tried with `HeaderStringFormat` and it is working now.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  I found my answer [here](http://www.codeease.com/wpf-groupbox-header-stringformat-binding.html).

```
<GroupBox>
    <GroupBox.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentTargetUnit, 
                                  Converter={StaticResource QuantityToTextConverter},
                                  ConverterParameter={x:Static enumerations:Quantity.Length},
                                  StringFormat=Foundation Height ({0})}">
    </GroupBox.Header>
</GroupBox>
```

You also need to remove the quotes from the StringFormat.  Also, in the link above, it shows placing "{}" before anything in the StringFormat.  If I recall correctly, you only need that if the place holder is first: StringFormat={}{0:C}

There are a limited amount of elements that will allow StringFormat Binding, TextBlock being one and GroupBox headers do not.

Comment: Give this man a cookie! Also, the `{}` is mandatory only if the `StringFormat` start with a place holder (like `{0}`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
StringFormat={}Foundation Height ({0})}">
```